# ObservableList: addListener followed by foreach

Tags: java, javafx, binding, observablelist

When I have an observable list, and want to do some stuff whenever an element is added or removed into it, I find myself doing the following code pattern very frequently:

```
    ObservableList<String> myDynamicList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    myDynamicList.add("My string 1");
    myDynamicList.add("My string 2");

    <...>

    Consumer<String> onElementAdded = s -> {
        logger.info("Added: " + s);
    };

    Consumer<String> onElementRemoved = s -> {
        logger.info("Removed: " + s);
    };

    // Follow list insertions & removals in the future
    myDynamicList.addListener((ListChangeListener<? super String>) c -> {
        while(c.next()) {
            c.getAddedSubList().forEach(onElementAdded);
            c.getRemoved().forEach(onElementRemoved);
        }
    });
    // "Synchronize" the initial state - call the same handler for all already inserted elements
    myDynamicList.forEach(onElementAdded);
```

Problems with this approach:

1. Code clutter: I have to define (at least) the `onElementAdded` consumer as a variable, to be used both in `addListener` and `forEach` calls. I.e., I cannot define the behavior directly in the `addListener` argument (which can be more concise).
2. There are two calls that need to be maintained consistent (i.e., when changing `onElementAdded` in `addListener`, do not forget to do the same in `forEach`)
3. I always have a doubt whether to put `addListener` or `forEach` call first. I reckon this doesn't matter if the list is only modified by one thread, and if not this will break anyway. But still...

So the question is, is there a better way of binding a listener to an observable list, and calling the same listener for all existing elements as though if they were just added into the list?

Comment: then simply add the listener to the list before you add elements to it and drop the `forEach`.

Comment: Thanks @wero, although it's kind of obvious :) If you can register a listener before the list is populated then it's fine. But sometimes you receive an (already populated) list as an argument in a function, and you need to bind to it.

Comment: If what wero writes is impossible for some reason, you can easily factor the code in a utility method.